# Blocktrail API, send from specific address?

Tags: php, api, bitcoin

I'm working on a platform which requires users to have access and control of bitcoins that they deposit. I figured it would be better to generate an address per user, rather than a whole wallet.

I need to create a transaction where I can specify the sending address as well as a receiving address. Is this even possible with Blocktrail? If so, how?

This is all being done in PHP.

Comment: Did you find way to send value from specific address?